# How to join two entities with ManyToMany relationship in the jpa query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jersey

I have two entities `User` and `Role`. Each user can have multiple roles.

User class

```java
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    )
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Role class:

```java
@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}
```

So a new joined table is being created called: **user_role**
[image]

I want to create a query for returning a list of users with `role_id` of 4, for example.
The query that I already tried:

```java
@Override
public List<User> getArtists() {
   return em.createQuery(
      "from User u, Role r where u.roles='4'",
      User.class
   ).getResultList();
}
```

How can I fix this query in order to retrieve a list of users with `role_id` of 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```java
List<User> users = em.createQuery(
   "select distinct u from User u join fetch u.roles rl where rl.id = :id",
    User.class)
.setHint( QueryHints.HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, false )
.setParameter("id", 1L)
.getResultList();
```

The `QueryHints.HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH` is added as an additional [performance optimization](https://in.relation.to/2016/08/04/introducing-distinct-pass-through-query-hint/). But please note that this optimization will work only with hibernate 5.2.2.Final ... 5.2.11.Final. It was broken in the 5.2.12.Final.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I will get the benfit of using SpringdataJpa with hibernate and just use this statment :
If you don't want to use query :

```
List<User> findByRoles_Id(Long id);
```

In your User Repository :

```
    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    List<User> findByRoles_Id(Long id);
}
```

Comment: To clarify this is SpringDataJPA, not JPA